# InvalidArgumentError: TensorScatterUpdate: Outer dimensions of indices and update must match

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, semantic-segmentation

I've been stuck on figuring out how to translate this PyTorch function to TensorFlow. The current function I have is throwing the below error:

`InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__TensorScatterUpdate_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Outer dimensions of indices and update must match. Indices shape: [256,256,1], updates shape:[1,256,256,4] [Op:TensorScatterUpdate]`

I am trying to generate tensor with of shape (1, num_classes) using the output of segmentation model.

Here is the PyTorch Function - In[8] (https://captum.ai/tutorials/Segmentation_Interpret)

```
def agg_segmentation_wrapper(model, inp):
    model_out = model.predict(inp)
    out_max = torch.argmax(model_out, dim=1, keepdim=True)
    # Creates binary matrix with 1 for original argmax class for each pixel
    # and 0 otherwise. Note that this may change when the input is ablated
    # so we use the original argmax predicted above, out_max.
    selected_inds = torch.zeros_like(model_out[0:1]).scatter_(1, out_max, 1)
    output = (model_out * selected_inds).sum(dim=(2,3))
    return output
```

Here is my attempt for an equivalent TF function

```
def agg_segmentation_wrapper(inp):
    model_out = model.predict(inp)
    out_max = tf.math.argmax(model_out, axis=-1)
    # Creates binary matrix with 1 for original argmax class for each pixel
    # and 0 otherwise. Note that this may change when the input is ablated
    # so we use the original argmax predicted above, out_max.
    selected_inds = tf.zeros_like(model_out[0:1])
    ones = tf.ones((selected_inds.shape))
    selected_inds = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(np.asarray(selected_inds, dtype=np.int32), np.asarray(out_max, dtype=np.int32), ones)
    return tf.reduce_sum(model_out * selected_inds, axis=(2, 3))
```